# Nodebox for windows

Tags: windows, macos, graph

Is there anything like [NodeBox](http://nodebox.net/code/index.php/Home) for Windows? Or is there any Windows version of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.processing.org/

> Processing is an open source programming language and environment for
>   people who want to create images, animations, and interactions.
>   Initially developed to serve as a software sketchbook and to teach
>   fundamentals of computer programming within a visual context,
>   Processing also has evolved into a tool for generating finished
>   professional work. Today, there are tens of thousands of students,
>   artists, designers, researchers, and hobbyists who use Processing for
>   learning, prototyping, and production.
>
> ```
> » Free to download and open source
> » Interactive programs using 2D, 3D or PDF output
> » OpenGL integration for accelerated 3D
> » For GNU/Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows
> » Projects run online or as double-clickable applications
> » Over 100 libraries extend the software into sound, video, computer vision, and more...
> » Well documented, with many books available
> ```

It's listed as the most popular alternative to Nodebox on http://alternativeto.net/software/nodebox/, and it's available on Mac, Windows and Linux. On alternativeto, you can see other popular alternatives, such as Vvvv (exclusively windows) Shoebot (cross-platform), Protovis, Evaldraw, and Context Free.